IBM Queue does not remove message after consumption
My IBM Queue does not remove message after consumption.
I will need to clear the queue before the second message sent will be processed else it will keep storing the message without it been processed.
When a message is sent to the queue, the message will be written into a table in databasse, but it was written into the database at first message and fails to write to a table in database for subsequent message been passed.
I will have to clear the queue before it will write to the table.
This USSD_ENROLMENT_NG_TWOQUEUE queue is called at this point

Message sent
USSD_ENROLMENT_NG_TWOQUEUE The queue processed the message at this point

Below is the properties diagram for the queue


Why don't you show your code. We are not clairvoyant.

Sounds like you are using MQGET with the browse option rather than destructively removing the message. If you showed your code we could advise the changes you would need to it.

I see you have updated your question with some flow diagrams, one of which contains an MQ Input node. Can you show us the Advanced properties of the MQ Input node please? There is a browse property there that I am guessing you have set?

@MoragHughson, I did not check the Browser only property

OK, so if you are not using browse, is it possible that your message gets rolled back as a result of some error in the processing and that is why it is still on the queue? I see you have Transaction Mode set to Automatic, which means the use of a transaction is dependant on the persistence of your messages. Can you tell us whether the message in question is persistent or non-persistent?

@MoragHughson, The message should not be persistent.

I guess that rules that theory out then. I see you have various trace nodes. What path does the message take through your various trace nodes? Perhaps that information might tell us something? Which terminal out of the MQ Input node does it take?

The official docs suggest you want to use DELETE, not GET to "destructively get a message from a queue"
https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-develop-mq-rest-api/
For example with Node.js (verbatim from docs)
function getMessage() {
// Call the operation
options.method = 'DELETE'
var request = https.request(options,(response) => {
  console.log('DELETE statusCode : ', response.statusCode);
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data',function(cbresponse) {
     console.log('Message is <%s>',cbresponse);
  });
});


Do you have some knowledge about OP's situation that led you to provide a REST based answer? Ther was no mention of the API in use as part of the question.

Language used is ESQL

@StephenAjose did you resolve this? e.g., is the MQOutput node set to Browse?

@richc MQOutput node does not have Browse property only the MQInput node does
